# AutoMapper 9 sets new EF Core 3.1 entities as Modified instead of Added

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, .net-core-3.1

TLDR: adding a new untracked entity type to a existing DTO's nested collection => existing DTO is mapped to its existing tracked entity type => EF Core tracker now sees the new entity's state as Modified instead of Added => error, there is nothing to be updated.

I ran into issues with AutoMapper and Entity Framework Core after we updated these packages to:

1. .NET Core 3.1
2. AutoMapper 9.0.0
3. EF Core 3.1.3

There is a simple scenario:

We have a DTO D that represents an entity E. Both the DTO and entity have a collection of child objects of type R that are EF entities as well (not the best design, but keep it like that, please).

1. I create a new DTO D (with empty collection), map it to entity E and save to the database. OK
2. I load the E from database, map it to DTO D (E is now tracked in EF Core). OK
3. I create a new object R and add it to the collection of DTO D. OK
4. I map the DTO D to its existing entity E, that is now tracked by the EF Core
5. Now there is an item for the object R in EF tracker that says, that R is **Modified** but definitely shoud be **Added**.

There is a minimumal working example of this behavior:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace AutomapperEFTest
{
    class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string databaseName = "TestDB";
            optionsBuilder
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: databaseName)
                .ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning));
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TestEntity>(e =>
            {
                e.ToTable("TestEntity");
                e.HasKey(t => t.Id);
                e.Property(t => t.SomeProperty);
                e.HasMany(t => t.RefValues)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.EntityId);
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<RefValue>(e =>
            {
                e.ToTable("RefValue");
                e.HasKey(r => r.Id);
                e.Property(r => r.EntityId)
                .HasColumnName("EntityId");
                e.Property(r => r.Value)
                .HasColumnName("Value");
            });
        }

        public DbSet<TestEntity> Entities => Set<TestEntity>();
        public DbSet<RefValue> RefValues => Set<RefValue>();
    }

    class TestEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RefValue> RefValues { get; set; }
    }

    class TestDto
    {
        public TestDto()
        {
            RefValues = new List<RefValue>();
        }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
        public List<RefValue> RefValues { get; set; }
    }

    class RefValue
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<TestDto, TestEntity>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
                .ForMember(d => d.SomeProperty, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SomeProperty))
                .ForMember(d => d.RefValues, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.RefValues))
                .ReverseMap();
            });

            using (var context = new TestContext())
            {
                var mapper = new Mapper(config);

                #region Works
                /*
                 * Adding both parent and child in one step works.
                var newDto = new TestDto() { Id = Guid.Parse("4C1596D7-C080-4E56-B2F6-1BAEBDC1CF7D"), SomeProperty = "Whatever" };                
                var newRef = new RefValue() { Id = Guid.Parse("526DC1A6-130B-41DC-9F74-32F9C807D7F5"), EntityId = Guid.Parse("4C1596D7-C080-4E56-B2F6-1BAEBDC1CF7D"), Value = "New Ref Value" };
                newDto.RefValues.Add(newRef);
                var entityToSave = mapper.Map<TestEntity>(newDto);
                context.Add(entityToSave);
                context.SaveChanges();
                */
                #endregion

                #region Data preparation
                var newDto = new TestDto(){Id = Guid.Parse("4C1596D7-C080-4E56-B2F6-1BAEBDC1CF7D"),SomeProperty = "Whatever"};
                var entity = mapper.Map<TestEntity>(newDto);
                context.Entities.Add(entity);
                context.SaveChanges();
                #endregion

                //Simple scenario - add a new item to a collection of an existing item
                var loadedEntity = context.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
                var loadedDto = mapper.Map<TestDto>(loadedEntity);
                var newRef = new RefValue(){Id = Guid.Parse("526DC1A6-130B-41DC-9F74-32F9C807D7F5"),EntityId = Guid.Parse("4C1596D7-C080-4E56-B2F6-1BAEBDC1CF7D"),Value = "New Ref Value"};
                loadedDto.RefValues.Add(newRef);
                //ensure it will be mapped to existing tracked item
                var entityToSave = mapper.Map(loadedDto, loadedEntity, typeof(TestDto), typeof(TestEntity));
                //Now the inner state of the newRef in the tracker is Modified but definitely should be Added
                //check it out: context.ChangeTracker.Entries<RefValue>().ToArray();

                //throws exception
                context.SaveChanges();                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How should be the AutoMapper configured to prevent this behavior?
This worked for us in previous versions - .NET Core 2.1, EF Core 1.x, AutoMapper 8.

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore.

Comment: This is EF Core (probably changed) behavior - happens even if you eliminate the AM and do directly `loadedEntity.RefValues.Add(newRef);`. I don't know if and how that worked in earlier EF Core versions since it's unclear that `RefValue` is new - it has `Id` and might be an existing record with different `EntityId`. I believe EF Core will identify it as new only if `Id` is auto-generated and has no value (or has the default value).

Comment: @IvanStoev: you hit the point! That is this breaking change in the new EF Core: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14616
I thought it affects only entities that have explicitely set the ValueGeneratedOn... feature in the model. However, this applies for all entities by default and needs to be set of with .ValueGeneratedNever().
Honestly, I did not expect such a huge change in the behavior. This is really a very breaking change.